# leveldb disable or prevent log file

Tags: leveldb

I have a CLI application that inserts new data and deletes information in the levelDB if it is no longer used,

however, what I am observing is, instead of the size getting smaller because we are deleting records the size is getting larger because every transaction to the database is logged in the leveldb .log file.
So it really defeats the purpose.

As a test, what I did is run two instance one without the delete (commented out) and one that does delete information. To my surprise, the one **with** delete routine has larger levelDb files compare to the one **without** that should be increasing in DB size.
This is due to leveldb .log file logging every transaction.

Any work around for this like disabling the level db logs or something?

Answer (score 0):

these logs are not an optional extra, they're part of the database structure. at some point they will disappear during (background) compaction.

i suspect you will see different patterns if you test with more data.